# Android app compilation warning "Runtime JAR file has version 1.4 which is older than required for API version 1.5"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin-android-extensions, android-r8

I do not use Kotlin but building an app with Android Studio generates the following warning:

```
C:\Users\h33\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.4.32\ef50bfa2c0491a11dcc35d9822edbfd6170e1ea2\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.32.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.4 which is older than required for API version 1.5
```

Could anyone shed some light on the cause of this?  How can I prevent this warning?